# Java Generics and base class

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T extends BaseEntity> implements BaseDao<T> {


    @Override
    public T createOrUpdate(T t, User user) {
        return createOrUpdate(t, true, user);
    }

    @Override
    public void addOnwerUserToEntity(String entityType, Long entityId, User user) {

        BaseEntity baseEntity = findBaseEntityById(entityType, entityId);

        baseEntity.addOwnerUser(user);

        createOrUpdate(baseEntity, user); // compilation error
    }

}
```

right now I have the following compilation error:

```
The method createOrUpdate(T, User) in the type BaseDaoImpl<T> is not applicable for the arguments (BaseEntity, User)
```

What am I doing wrong, why `createOrUpdate` method doesn't accept `BaseEntity` object and how to fix it ?

Comment: Why would it accept a `BaseEntity` value? You've declared `createOrUpdate` to accept a `T`.

Comment: It's often easier to understand when you replace the classes by concrete examples. T = Banana. BaseEntity = Fruit. You define a method createOrUpdate(Banana), and you call it with an argument of type Fruit. A Fruit is not necessarily a Banana. So the compiler doesn't accept the method call.

Comment: But T is declared to accept BaseEntity and subclasses. Right now I don't understand why it doesn't accept BaseEntity..

Comment: We can't really know _how to fix it_ without knowing your use case (or what `findBaseEntityById` is).

Comment: List<T> accepts any class as generis type. But you can't add a Fruit to a List<Banana>. Because the Fruit could be an Apple, or a Lemon, i.e. another type than T.

Comment: I got it, thanks !

Comment: @alexanoid You may want to take a look at the [PECS mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, `T` is not necessarily a `BaseEntity`. You could instantiate class `BaseDaoImpl` like so:

```
class Widget extends BaseEntity {...}
BaseDaoImpl<Widget> base = new BaseDaoImpl<>();
```

In this case, `T` is a `Widget`, and so the method `createOrUpdate(...)` becomes:

```
public Widget createOrUpdate(Widget t, User user) {
```

and you cannot call that with just a `BaseEntity`.

Comment: By the way, perhaps you could change createOrUpdate to accept and return a BaseEntity.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
BaseEntity baseEntity = findBaseEntityById(entityType, entityId);
```

to

```
T baseEntity = findBaseEntityById(entityType, entityId);
```

I assume that `BaseDao<T>.findBaseEntityById()` has return type `T`. If not, it should! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are hoping that your "T extends BaseEntity" covers BaseEntity and it could be passed anywhere where you put 'T' as parameter. Not such luck my friend. Please review your understanding of generics .